# TypeScript tsc command halts in the middle and does not return back to command prompt on ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-ec2, tsc

The nodeJS backend project I'm working on has to be compiled from typescript in the last step. I am able to compile this project on my local but I'm running into this issue where the compile gets halted or is taking too long on the ec2 server. Also I have compiled and updated this project on the server many times before I faced this issue. I have also tried empty the build folder and then run the command and nothing is output in the build folder.

There are no compile errors on my local and return to command prompt successfully.

When I run the command with `tsc --traceResolution -p tsconfig.json`. This is the end logs I get on my terminal after which I see no further progress.

> Found 'package.json' at '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser/package.json'.
> 'package.json' does not have a 'typesVersions' field.

> File '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser.d.ts' does not exist.
> 'package.json' does not have a 'typings' field.
> 'package.json' has 'types' field 'index.d.ts' that references '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser/index.d.ts'.
> File '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser/index.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
> Resolving real path for '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser/index.d.ts', result '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser/index.d.ts'.

> ======== Module name 'yargs-parser' was successfully resolved to '/home/ubuntu/nomqa-backend-api/node_modules/@types/yargs-parser/index.d.ts' with Package ID '@types/yargs-parser/index.d.ts@15.0.0'. ========

I can see that all modules are getting resolved the same on both local and on ec2 server.

**System configs:**

Local: Node version 12.18.2, NPM version 6.14.5

EC2: Node version 10.21.0, NPM 6.14.5

Dev Dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
"@types/body-parser": "^1.17.1",
"@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
"@types/express": "^4.17.2",
"@types/hapi__joi": "^17.1.2",
"@types/ioredis": "^4.14.3",
"@types/jest": "^25.1.3",
"@types/joi": "^14.3.4",
"@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.3.5",
"@types/morgan": "^1.7.37",
"@types/mysql": "^2.15.13",
"@types/node": "^12.12.22",
"@types/socket.io": "^2.1.8",
"@types/socket.io-redis": "^1.0.26",
"@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
"@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.1",
"@types/uuid": "^3.4.6",
"@types/validator": "^12.0.1",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.21.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.21.0",
"concurrently": "^5.1.0",
"http-server": "^0.12.1",
"jest": "^25.1.0",
"sleep-ms": "^2.0.1",
"supertest": "^4.0.2",
"swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
"ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
"ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44",
"typescript": "^3.7.3"
 }
```

package.json dependencies

```
{
    "@hapi/joi": "^16.1.8",
"@nemospeculo/express-sanitized": "^1.0.1",
"@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.2",
"apidoc": "^0.23.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.738.0",
"bcrypt": "^4.0.0",
"bluebird": "^3.7.2",
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"cors": "^2.8.5",
"dotenv": "^8.2.0",
"eslint": "^6.8.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"ioredis": "^4.16.0",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
"moment": "^2.27.0",
"mongoose": "^5.11.8",
"morgan": "^1.9.1",
"mysql": "^2.18.1",
"socket.io": "^2.3.0",
"socket.io-redis": "^5.3.0",
"uuid": "^7.0.1"
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {

"target": "es6",
"lib": [
  "es2019"
],
"module": "commonjs",
"esModuleInterop": true,
"allowJs": true,
"checkJs": true,
"sourceMap": true,
"outDir": "./build",
"strict": false,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"resolveJsonModule": true,
},
"include": [                                                                                                                                                                                       
  "./src/*"                                                                                                                                                                                          
],

"exclude": ["node_modules" ,"coverage" ,"tests","swagger.json","**/*.spec.ts","jest.config.js"] ,
"files": ["./src/types/global.d.ts"]

}
```

Comment: Can you share your tsconfig.json and the rest of your package.json?

Comment: @cdimitroulas done, excuse me for the delay, but this issue is still prevalent on the server instance, your help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Also I have compiled and updated this project on the server many times before I faced this issue. I have also tried empty the build folder and then run the command and nothing is output in the build folder.

Comment: It's quite difficult to help if you say that this runs fine locally but not on AWS. That would suggest that there's some issue in the way you are deploying to EC2 or that there is some misconfiguration on the infra level.
The fact that you are using different Node versions locally vs on EC2 isn't ideal. Have you tried with Node 10 locally to see if that is the issue?

Comment: Please update your Ec2 Instance Type if you are running at t2.micro